# Most performant way to take 2 lists of objects and perform distinct method calls on duplicate and unique objects

Tags: java

I have a two lists of the same type of objects.  I want to perform a method call on every object that is contained in both lists.  Then I want to call a different method on every object that is only contained in list 1 and not list 2.

I've been working on legacy projects with a very old JDK until recently.  So my initial thought is to just loop through list 1, put all the duplicates in separate list, put all the unique objects in to a different list.  Then once I have the two lists I would loop through each list calling the respective methods.  I am almost certain this is not the performant way to do things.  Would this be a good use case for streams?  Streams are a pretty new concept to me and I've only ever used them with a simple filter to return a filtered list.

So any help on the best practices way to solve this problem I would super appreciate.   Thank you!

Edit: When I use the word duplicate I mean objects that are contained in both list 1 and list 2.  There will be no duplicates contained within a single list.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate? Only  objects that are also contained in list 2? Or also duplicates within list 1?

Comment: I made an edit to the original post, sorry for not being clear enough.  When I say duplicate I mean objects that are contained in list 1 and list 2.  There will be no duplicates within the same list.

Comment: The objects in the list have their `equals` and `hashcode` methods (Not the `equals` from `Object`?

Comment: In this case, can a *duplicate object* be objects with the same identity, objects with the same value, or both?

Comment: Yes the Objects have Overriden hashCode and equals methods.

Comment: Do you want to call the method on objects from both lists, or just on objects from list1 depending on whether they're in list2?

Answer (score 0):

Looping the first two list seems unavoidable. Also, I don't think that using `Iterable.forEach` vs `Stream.forEach` really matters when just looping (Or at least it hasn't mattered in my experience. I lack actual, technical confirmation that the performance differences are noticeable). With that said, you could try like in the following:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        List<Integer> list1 = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> list2 = Stream.of(2, 4, 6, 8, 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        System.out.println("Method A on list1");
        list1.forEach(System.out::println);
        
        System.out.println("Method A on list2");
        list2.forEach(obj -> System.out.println(obj));
        
        System.out.println("Method B on those of list1 not in list2");
        list1.stream().filter(obj -> !list2.contains(obj)).forEach(System.out::print);
    }
    
}
```

In this snippet, I have two list which contain duplicate objects (As per your description). You need to run Method A on every one of them, so you loop through both lists. Note that the call on list1 is the same as in list2, just different syntax depending of the method you need to call.

Then you need to `filter` out those on list1 that also are in list2, and run the Method B on the resulting collection. The output of this code is as follows:

```java
Method A on list1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
Method A on list2
2
4
6
8
0
Method B on those of list1 not in list2
13579
```

As for whether or not this is a good use case for Streams, I'd say is a 'fair' case. Looping through the whole of `list1` and `list2` is probably not since your are not doing anything else. There is no reason (That I can think of / am aware of) that says otherwise. Using `List.forEach` is perfectly fine.

For the second case, I think `Stream.filter` is the tool for the job. Besides filtering, it doesn't modify the list it applies to neither it creates a new one.

Finally, while thinking about performance is important, it should be attended when it is needed. If the feature using this code runs slow, then it is time to visit it and see what can be done. For example, you could 'run' the three `forEach` methods in parallel by doing `List.stream.parallel` before them, but whether or not is needed is something that real usage scenarios will tell (And if the order in which the methods are executed is important or not).

Answer (score 0):

The naïve implementation would be something like:

```
for (item1: list1){
  if (list2.contains(item1)) {
    methodA(item1);
  } else {
    methodB(item1);
  }
}
```

The only thing that can be improved much is the `list2.contains(item1)` part. If list2 is an ArrayList, the .contains method will loop over it and compare each and every item, so you will have an O(m*n) for the whole process, with m=size(list1) and n=size(list2)

One improvement would be to sort list2 beforehand, so you can use binarysearch. This would result in a O((m+n)*log(n)):

```
Collections.sort(list2);
for (item1: list1){
  if (Collections.binarySearch(list2, item1) != -1) {
    methodA(item1);
  } else {
    methodB(item1);
  }
}
```

An alternative is to copy list2 into a HashSet, which would result in O(m+n), but with extra memory usage:

```
Set set2 = new HashSet(list2);
for (item1: list1){
  if (set2.contains(item1)) {
    methodA(item1);
  } else {
    methodB(item1);
  }
}
```